# How to print main key value of JSON in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, json

Below is the similar styled array which I'm using. I need to print that **Product names** (i.e. Product1 name, Product2 name, Product3 name). How to achieve that

```
{
    'Product1 name':[{
        price: '20',
        color:'red'
    }],
    'Product2 name':[{
        price: '30',
        color:'green'
    }],
        'Product3 name':[{
        price: '40',
        color:'blue'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$scope.products = { 'Product1 name':[{ price: '20', color:'red' }], 'Product2 name':[{ price: '30', color:'green' }], 'Product3 name':[{ price: '40', color:'blue' }] }` -

Your view should be like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,val) in products">{{ key }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to create a new array of product names

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.products = {
  'Product1 name':[{
    price: '20',
    color:'red'
  }],
  'Product2 name':[{
    price: '30',
    color:'green'
  }],
    'Product3 name':[{
    price: '40',
    color:'blue'
  }]
};

$scope.productNames = Object.keys($scope.products);
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="name in productNames">{{name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

//Angular code

```
<ul  *ngFor = "let data of  allDataFromAws | async " >

<--- Data is printing in a key-value format without double quotes
    <li *ngFor = "let child of data | keyvalue">
        {{child.key}} : <strong>{{child.value}}</strong>
    </li>

<--- Data in JSON format --->

   {{data |json}}

</ul>
```